# Working out vs. active lifestyle

Tags: workout, health, bicycling

Is an "active lifestyle" enough activity for maintaining health? For example, I don't do any sports. However, five times a week I cycle to work (about 20-25 minutes one way, very slow pace), almost never take the lift and do yoga/pilates once a week. I used to go to the gym but I stopped a few months ago, because of lack of time. At first I thought I'm doing something wrong, but maybe just cycling and occasional activity is enough? I don't need to lose weight.

Comment: I think it depends on what your definition of "maintaining health" is.  Each of us has our own definition of that.  You should probably expand on yours.

Comment: I believe that health is the optimal state of the body. This means that everything functions properly and should keep functioning properly in the future.

Answer (score 2):

Good health outcomes generally come from cardiovascular exertion,  I think the recommended minimum is 3x20 mins /week. Your slow cycle to work is better than nothing but I'd suspect your heart rate isn't elevated much. The stairs probably does raise your hr,  but not for long. There are hormonal benefits of lifting weights and a multitude of health benefits from achieving regular intensive cardio. 
Is it enough to maintain your fitness level,    well,  that depends on how fit you are. The fitter you are the harder you'll need to work to maintain it. Turn that bike ride into something that gets your heart rate into the 70% of your Max and it might be.

Comment: Can you add some evidence to back your claims?

Comment: And how do you recommend he know his "maximum" heart rate? Why 70%? What hormonal benefits?

Comment: @JohnP it's colloquially known that maximum heart rate is approximately 220 minus your age.

Comment: @JohnP Exercising At 70% is common,  safe https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pubmed/24866048 and effective https://www.cdc.gov/physicalactivity/basics/measuring/heartrate.htm

Comment: @JohnP  Growth hormone and Testosterone https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pubmed/2796409

Comment: "colloquially known" = bro science. 220-age has been completely debunked, and was based on limited, flawed data to begin with. 70% may be safe, but again, how do you determine the MHR? And since comments are ephemeral, it would be better if you summarized those links and added them into the answer (Without the 220-age, that needs to be killed with fire and removed from the face of the earth).

Comment: You're  being unnecessarily pedantic because of your previous deletion of my explanations,  besides it's close enough especially when we're  talking about 70%. Please feel free to link to a peer reviewed study suggesting the algorithm has been "debunked"

Comment: @JohnP amongst those who subscribe to the 220-age method are the American Heart Association  http://www.heart.org/HEARTORG/HealthyLiving/PhysicalActivity/FitnessBasics/Target-Heart-Rates_UCM_434341_Article.jsp#mainContent , polar,  the largest manufacturer of heart rate measurement equipment http://support.polar.com/us-en/support/How_to_calculate_target_heart_rate_zone_  , the cdc https://www.cdc.gov/physicalactivity/basics/measuring/heartrate.htm  and hundreds of others, it is still an acceptable method for approximation and entirely suitable for the above question. #pedantic

Comment: http://www.onlinejacc.org/content/37/1/153, https://www.asep.org/asep/asep/Robergs2.pdf, http://europepmc.org/abstract/med/17468581 - Unfortunately 220-age is entrenched and commonly known, even though it was based on limited data and bad extrapolation. And I'm not being pedantic because I deleted anything. I'm attempting to correct a fallacy. You can do your own research and draw your own conclusions.

Comment: @johnP lol,  the study you quote is specifically for Children afflicted with cerebral palsy!!!  Broscience indeed.

Comment: @james - Whoops. Missed that one. I noticed you disregarded the others. I've tried to educate, if you choose to cling to outmoded, proven bad information not much I can do.

Comment: I reiterate,  the 220 minus age method is entirely appropriate for estimation,  especially considering the context of which the question is written. If it's good enough for hundreds of cardiologists and medical organisations it's good enough when approximating a 50-80% window for a lady riding a bike to work.

Answer (score 0):

If you are able to be active without working out, you should be able to maintain your health. You might have heard about the Blue Zones (regions of the world where people live long lives), their inhabitants do not go to the gym for workout. However, their lifestyles are very active. A lot of their activity has to do with things like farming, gardening, walking up and down the hills, etc. In other words, humans were born to move, walk, carry different weights - and this is all makes a natural workout. If your lifestyle is active enough, I guess you could go without working out in the gym. However, if like most people you spend hours at the desk, then incorporating an actual workout routine is a necessity.